# A large CSV/TXT file need to be split into multiple small files based on the number of lines given. using GO bufio.NewScanner

Tags: go

I'm new to GOLANG. I try to do one tiny task .
A large CSV/TXT file need to be split into multiple small files based on the number of lines given.
Input File  :  abc.csv  (assume 200 lines),   NoofLines required per file: 50
output File:  abc_1.csv,  abc_2.csv, abc_3.csv, abc_4.csv
Let me to paste the code into this thread.  Currently my script is creating 4 files.
Each file contain not expected data and format.
Is there an easy way to create?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("abc.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    sc := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    lines := make([]string, 0)

    // Read through 'tokens' until an EOF is encountered.
    linecnt := 1
    filecnt := 1
    var fname string
    fname = fmt.Sprint("abc_", filecnt, ".csv")
    file, _ = os.Create(fname)
    fmt.Println("file :", fname)
    for sc.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, sc.Text())
        if linecnt == 50 {
            linecnt = 0
            filecnt++
            //var fname string
            fname = fmt.Sprint("abc_", filecnt, ".csv")
            file, _ = os.Create(fname)
            writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
            defer writer.Flush()
            writer.Write(lines)
            defer file.Close()
            fmt.Println("file :", fname)
        } else {
            linecnt++
            writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
            defer writer.Flush()
            writer.Write(lines)
        }

    }

    if err := sc.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```